# Scipy convolve2d with subsampling like Theano's conv2d?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, theano

I wish to perform 2D convolution on images of size 600 X 400 using a 10 X 10 filter. The filter is not separable. `scipy.signal.convolve2d` works well for me currently but, I am expecting a lot bigger images soon.

To counter that, I have two ideas

1. resizing images
2. subsampling (or striding)?

Focusing on the subsampling part, theano has a function which does convolution the same way as scipy convolve2d, see [theano conv2d](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/signal/conv.html#theano.tensor.signal.conv.conv2d)

It also has the subsampling option too. But, installing theano on windows has been painful to me. How do I get subsampling work with `scipy.signal.convolve2d`? Any other alternatives (which doesn't require me installing me some heavyweight library)?

Comment: Is your filter going to grow with the images? In that case you may try and look into [fftconovolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html) because IIRC unlike many other numerical computing softwares scipy doesn't use fft per default. Of course, if your filter stays at 10x10 this won't gain you much if anything at all.

Comment: My filter will remain the same. I actually moved to fftconvolve. And it is indeed fast (2X for my purposes). However, it too doesn't have any subsampling option

Comment: I've added some code to the A. Only 1d I'm afraid, but should be straightforward to generalise. Have a look.

Comment: As well, you can try [Intel Theano](https://github.com/intel/theano) which will be very fast in CPU with optimized convolution, relu and other primitives.

Comment: @Patric That is indeed a good idea. However, I share this code with a few people who work on different systems, hence not preferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement subsampling by hand, I'll only sketch 1d for simplicity. Say you want to sample s = d * f on a regular subgrid with spacing k. Then your nth sample is s_nk = sum_i=0^10 f_i d_nk-i. The thing to observe here is that the indices of f and d always sum to a multiple of k. This suggests splitting it up into sub-sums s_nk = sum_j=0^k-1 sum_i=0^10/k f_j+ik d_-j+(n-i)k. So what you need to do is: subsample d and f at grids with spacing k at all offsets 0, ..., k-1. Convolve all pairs of subsampled d and f whose offsets sum to 0 or k and add the results.

Here's some code for 1d. It roughly implements the above, only the grids are placed slightly differently to make index management easier. The second function does it the stupid way, i.e. computes the full convolution and then decimates. It is for testing the first function against.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

def ss_conv(d1, d2, decimate):
    n = (len(d1) + len(d2) - 1) // decimate
    out = np.zeros((n,))
    for i in range(decimate):
        d1d = d1[i::decimate]
        d2d = d2[decimate-i-1::decimate]
        cv = signal.convolve(d1d, d2d, 'full')
        out[:len(cv)] += cv
    return out

def conv_ss(d1, d2, decimate):
    return signal.convolve(d1, d2, 'full')[decimate-1::decimate]
```

Edit: 2d version:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

def ss_conv_2d(d1, d2, decy, decx):
    ny = (d1.shape[0] + d2.shape[0] - 1) // decy
    nx = (d1.shape[1] + d2.shape[1] - 1) // decx
    out = np.zeros((ny, nx))
    for i in range(decy):
        for j in range(decx):
            d1d = d1[i::decy, j::decx]
            d2d = d2[decy-i-1::decy, decx-j-1::decx]
            cv = signal.convolve2d(d1d, d2d, 'full')
            out[:cv.shape[0], :cv.shape[1]] += cv
    return out

def conv_ss_2d(d1, d2, decy, decx):
    return signal.convolve2d(d1, d2, 'full')[decy-1::decy, decx-1::decx]
```

Comment: This is interesting. Let me try this out. I still am not sure if I can get the 2D version working

Comment: Thanks Paul for the answer. I actually got the 2D working, but yours is little faster. I will mark this accepted

Comment: However, I dont understand which one of them is faster and why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Which one of which? Do you mean `ss_conv_2d` and `conv_ss_2d`? Of those the first is faster, essentially because it only calculates what's absolutely necessary, whereas the second computes the full convolution and then discards most of it. When using `convolve2d` the speedup should be roughly decy x decx, maybe a bit less because of the overhead for the loops. When using `fftconvolve` the speedup should be less because `fftconvolve` saves more (compared to `convolve2d`) on large operands.

Comment: Interesting. But won't those two nested for loops will make the speed of ss_conv2d go down? I timed your methods, and the ss_conv2d is marginally faster.

Comment: Yes, especially if your image and filter are small, then I expect the overhead of the loops and additional code to be non-negligible. Unfortunately I see no way of vectorising the code, because `fftconvolve` is not flexible enough (if you give it a stack of images it will also convolve along the z-axis). Btw. did you try (in the code) replacing `convolve2d` with `fftconvolve`? Would be interesting because your subsampled filter may be so small, that `fftconvolve` is actually slower in this case.

Comment: I did. fftconvolve is indeed slower than convolve2d